# How can i loop through a list of items and push their data values into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to loop through a list of items that all have data-ids added, I basically want to push each of these values into an array but not sure how this can be achieved or where I need to place the loop index, the code I've got so far is:

JS

```
// Find all boxes and length
var box = _.els.grid.children(),
          box_l = box.length,
          i = 0;
          box_arr = [];

//create array of all box datas
for ( i; i <= box_l; i++ ) {
  box_arr.push( box.data('id')[i] );
}
console.log( box_arr );
```

HTML

```
<ul id="grid" class="clearfix">
    <li class="a" data-id="1"></li>
    <li class="b" data-id="2"></li>
    <li class="c" data-id="3"></li>
    <li class="d" data-id="4"></li>
    <li class="e" data-id="5"></li>
    <li class="f" data-id="6"></li>
    <li class="g" data-id="7"></li>
    <li class="h" data-id="8"></li>
    <li class="i" data-id="9"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What isn't working with that?

Comment: i get an array of [undefined, undefined, undefined ... ] ?

Comment: sorry Mark what does OR mean?

Comment: I posted an answer as it was too detailed for a comment

Answer (score 2):

You could use the jQuery [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method:

```
​var arr = $("#grid li").map(function() {
        return $(this).data("id");
}).get();​​​​​​​
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/xjeUz/).

The problem with your existing code is that `data` in your case just returns a string, not an array, so `box.data('id')[i]` is undefined.

Comment: cool, ive never used .map before. will have a read up on this method.

Comment: Using it with `.get()` feels hacky though.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine - You do if you want an array, and not an instance of jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/xjeUz/2/

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is fix this line:

```
box_arr.push( box.data('id')[i] );
```

You only want to fetch the ID of the i-th element in box:

```
for (i = 0; i < box_l; i++) {
  box_arr.push( box.eq(i).data('id') );
}
```

However, different approaches utilizing map() etc. are probably a better (cleaner) choice.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ids = [];

$('li[data-id]').each(function (index, value) {
    ids.push($(value).data('id'));
});
```

Answer (score -4):

Updated since question answers were never accepted.

THIS: just seems messed up: (see the comments on each)

```
var box = _.els.grid.children(), // what is "_.els.grid."? _ is undefined
          box_l = box.length, 
          i = 0; //semi colon?
          box_arr = []; //no var?
```

ONE reason I put var on every variable. (but that is not the issue)

jQuery answer:

```js
var box = $('#grid > li');
var box_arr = [];

box.each(function() {
  box_arr.push($(this).data('id'));
});
console.log(box_arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="grid" class="clearfix">
  <li class="a" data-id="1"></li>
  <li class="b" data-id="2"></li>
  <li class="c" data-id="3"></li>
  <li class="d" data-id="4"></li>
  <li class="e" data-id="5"></li>
  <li class="f" data-id="6"></li>
  <li class="g" data-id="7"></li>
  <li class="h" data-id="8"></li>
  <li class="i" data-id="9"></li>
</ul>
```

NOTE: I keep getting some down votes on this BUT the way this is written `box_arr = [];` defaults to `window.box_arr = [];`, just pointing that out in case someone thinks global JavaScript variable are a good idea (I do not) - which is the point of this and not the stylistic portion (which I do not really care either way about really)

BUT more importantly perhaps `_.els.grid.children()` that `_` IS undefined in the question so this is a useless line and might as well be `var box = undefined,` which is why the OP code actually fails as posted.

Updated to a snippet to show that the code actually works.

HTML5 example:

```js
var box = document.getElementById('grid').children,
  box_l = box.length,
  i = 0,
  box_arr = [],
  numbersArray = []; // actual numbers
//put data in arrays
for (i; i < box_l; i++) {
  box_arr.push(box[i].dataset.id);
  numbersArray.push(box[i].dataset.id * 1);
}
console.log("Array:", box_arr, numbersArray);
```

```html
<ul id="grid" class="clearfix">
  <li class="a" data-id="1"></li>
  <li class="b" data-id="2"></li>
  <li class="c" data-id="3"></li>
  <li class="d" data-id="4"></li>
  <li class="e" data-id="5"></li>
  <li class="f" data-id="6"></li>
  <li class="g" data-id="7"></li>
  <li class="h" data-id="8"></li>
  <li class="i" data-id="9"></li>
</ul>
```

Without jQuery:

```js
var box = document.getElementById('grid').children,
  box_l = box.length,
  i = 0,
  box_arr = [];
//console.log(box, box_l);
//create array of all box datas
for (i; i < box_l; i++) {
  box_arr.push(box[i].getAttribute('data-id'));
}
console.log("Array:", box_arr);
```

```html
<ul id="grid" class="clearfix">
  <li class="a" data-id="1"></li>
  <li class="b" data-id="2"></li>
  <li class="c" data-id="3"></li>
  <li class="d" data-id="4"></li>
  <li class="e" data-id="5"></li>
  <li class="f" data-id="6"></li>
  <li class="g" data-id="7"></li>
  <li class="h" data-id="8"></li>
  <li class="i" data-id="9"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is personal style. Except for the semicolon typo and the wrong indentation, I prefer the first style. Other people do. Other people don't. This doesn't deserve an answer though.

Comment: sorry i = 0; was a typo, i don't see why you would need to add var to every variable though since one + , convers them all?

Comment: Stylistic answers are at best meant for comments. nothing of value here.

Comment: And even though it is too much detailed to be a comment (seeing your comment on the question), this still doesn't answer the question in any way.

Comment: It is NOT just about the semi-colon but really about the actual code, that was just a symptom.

Comment: Apart from that typo, the code looks fine to me. Having a `var` in each line just clutters the whole thing up.

Comment: NOTE NONE of the other answers actually point out the `var box =` is undefined because `_` is undefined, edited to make that explicit.